# How to protect get/post parameters?

Tags: php, security, http, nginx

Lately I see more errors in logs regarding get/post parameters on a nginx/php hosted website. I have some basic checks(sanitization) in place but I think I haven't done enough.

Some of my checks have revealed attempts on an "id" parameter:

```
Parameter ID was not a number! Parameter was: function id() {
var s = '';
while (s.length < 32) {
    s  = Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, '');
}
return s;
}" while reading response header from upstream, client: ...
```

So basically I was expecting a number and got a very interesting string. I don't even know what they were trying to achieve with that code, it seems to be javascript and my server is php.

I was thinking of checking even string parameters by a regex.

What kind of checks do you recommend for get/post parameters on a php website?

Comment: I guess they were trying to inject a JS code to change their ID when it was displayed (the code is run). Good job stopping them!

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the type of data you're trying to retrieve. In your case with (integer) numbers, I think what you're doing is fine: if they don't input an integer value, then just return an error like you're doing.

For text, I think sanitization (removing illegal characters), such as with `htmlentities()` should be enough to prevent hacking attacks.

But again, it really depends on the level of security and data types you use.